# SendKeys, экранирование скобок

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток.

Есть следующий код:

```
Char = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < Char.Count(); i++)
{
      SendKeys.SendWait(Char[i].ToString());
}
```

Все бы хорошо, но когда text (переменная типа string) содержит в себе скобку - вылетает исключение: "Несоответствие между числом групп и разделителей."

Как можно выйти из ситуации?

Comment: Простите, а что именно вылетает — `ToString` или `SendWait`? Или код, _которому_ посылается строка?

Comment: @z668: [документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) говорит:

> The plus sign (`+`), caret (`^`), percent sign (`%`), tilde (`~`), and parentheses `()` have special meanings to `SendKeys`. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces (`{}`). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "`{+}`". To specify brace characters, use "`{{}`" and "`{}}`". Brackets (`[ ]`) have no special meaning to `SendKeys`, but you must enclose them in braces.

Так что проверяйте и добавляйте фигурные скобки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
static readonly HashSet<char> charsToEscape =
    { '+', '^', '%', '~', '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']' };

static string EscapeIfNeeded(char c)
{
    if (charsToEscape.Contains(c))
        return "{" + c + "}";
    else
        return c.ToString();
}

// ...
foreach (var c in text) // ToCharArray не нужно
    SendKeys.SendWait(EscapeIfNeeded(c));
```